# Django template tags don't show HTML template correctly

Tags: html, django

I have an HTML template that I want code with django in back-end to develop my site.
I have trouble with django template tags. when I use them, such as `{% for %}` the website template output is corrupted and don't show code of `models.py` and `views.py`.

`home_page.html`:

```
<section>
            <div class="gap100 no-top overlap-75">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="servic-category">
                        <div class="row merged">
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                            {% for training_course in training_courses %}
                                <div class="category-box">
                                    <i class="fa fa-google-wallet"></i>
                                    <h2>{{ training_course.title }}</h2>
                                    <p>{{ training_course.description }}</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="main-btn" title="">ادامه مطلب</a>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section><!-- services section -->
```

`views.py` :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from training_courses import TrainingCourses

def home_page(request):
    training_courses = TrainingCourses.objects.all()
    context = {
        'training_courses': training_courses
    }
    return render(request, 'home_page.html', context)
```

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class TrainingCourses (models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name= 'عنوان')
    description=models.TextField(verbose_name='توضیحات')
    link=models.URLField(max_length=100, verbose_name='آدرس')
     
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='برنامه آموزشی'
        verbose_name_plural='برنامه های آموزشی'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Where is `object_list` returned in views ?

Comment: You refere to a object_list in the {% for .... %} tag but in the view there is no object_list in context.

Comment: I corrected that code, but the problem still not solved.